# Trouble with webscraping (Null list)

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am currently trying to get the ranks of a players but always come back with a null list.
Been struggling for a while, would really appreciate some help and any tips for future project to tackle these issues. Or places to better understand beautifulsoup in general

```
import requests as req
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

id = "epic"
tag = "random"
url = f"https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/profile/{id}/{tag.lower()}/overview"
html = req.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(html,"lxml")
line = soup.findAll("div",{"class":"rank"})
print(line)
```

Here's what I'm trying to get:

[image: Screenshot showing desired element]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Loading response with the `requests` doesn't work here, simply because the site loads contents *dynamically* & thus you need to use some `webdriver`.

Here's what I've come up with:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.options import Options

options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
driver = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r"driver/geckodriver.exe", options=options)

id = "epic"
tag = "random"
url = f"https://rocketleague.tracker.network/rocket-league/profile/{id}/{tag.lower()}/overview"

driver.get(url)
driver.implicitly_wait(2) #allow some time to fully load, you may tweak accordingly
ranks = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector(r'[class="rank"]')

for i in ranks:
    print(i.text)
driver.quit()
```

Resulting in:

```
#695,273 • Top 32%
#1,409,786 • Bottom 26%
#1,240,839 • Bottom 43%
#1,195,373 • Bottom 45%
#875,794 • Top 41%
#874,338 • Top 41%
#1,530,195 • Bottom 29%
#960,411 • Top 45%
Unranked Division I
#1,663,447 • Top 33%
Gold III Division III
#2,974,386 • Bottom 29%
Platinum II Division III
#2,879,016 • Bottom 40%
Platinum II Division II
#2,363,741 • Top 50%
Gold III Division III
#2,407,466 • Bottom 42%
Platinum II Division I
#2,054,002 • Top 48%
Gold II Division II
#2,321,030 • Bottom 41%
```